# Csv with Weka how to add comma as a value not a seperator

Tags: algorithm, csv, weka

I have a dataset. With using this dataset, I must run machine learning algorithms. But my dataset has some elements which also has comma but when I convert CSV to Arff this comma values does not recognized.

Example;

```
a,b,c
asdasd'%sdas,1,5,4234
```

My elements are 
    asdasd'%sdas    1,5 4234

But I could not handle the value has comma inside it.
I tried these

```
a,b,c
asdasd'%sdas,1\,5,4234

a,b,c
asdasd'%sdas,"1,5",4234
```

How can I pass comma valued element while using weka? My another wonder is how pass an element as string which has special chars like  "sdas&%',+" Is it possible or something similar with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
"asdasd'%sdas","1,5",4234
```

You can send strings that contain special characters just like this.